# What do first derivatives, factorials, and alternating signs have to do with explicit and recursive forms of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations

I'm a math teacher now, although a few years ago I was finishing up my M.Ed. As part of my studies, I was tasked with conducting my own study of high school level topics and finding unique results. As a student, I had always been fascinated with the idea of converting sequences in explicit form into recursive form, especially since nowhere could I find a general formula.

The images below are my submission to my graduate school and an explanation as to the formula I arrived at for converting polynomial sequences in explicit form into their recursive counterparts.

My ***BIG*** question is why? Why does this formula involve the nth derivative, the nth factorial, and an alternating sign?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like [Taylor series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an analytic function such as a polynomial, we have [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Analytic_functions):

$f(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(t-x)^n$.

Take $t=x-1$ to get your formula.